# How do I get remote access with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, remote-access

I want to connect to a specific set of laptops on our domain remotely. I need to have it log to the C drive, and search out a specific folder, then report back on a specific file contained in the folder. 
I have found scripts that have shown me how to locate and show if the path exists, along with a specific file name at the end of the path. I created a test file on my laptop and the script worked flawlessly. 
However, I need it to reach out over our domain, log into the target laptop, locate the file and contents then create a report on the findings. This will need to be done over VPN to the devices on our network.

My main issue at this point is finding the commands to invoke PowerShell to log onto the remote computers.

Comment: You should post a sample of what you have tried so far, even if it is just a local script. People are a lot more willing to help then when they see you have tried something. You could look at using [Invoke-Command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7) as a starting point, but you would need to know that the target machines will accept a [connection](https://support.infrasightlabs.com/article/how-to-enable-winrm-on-windows-servers-clients/) and that the firewall rules on your VPN will support the use of WinRM ports.

Comment: [`Get-Help about_remote_FAQ`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Remote_FAQ)

Comment: Thank you for the input. As I said, I am new to this environment. I know absolutely nothing about it. I tried a script that allowed me to check for a document in a file name on my own laptop. That worked properly. It was a very simple script. I am not asking for anyone to do this for me. I simply want to know if what I need to do is even possible.

Comment: So what needs to be done is this. I would need to invoke the powershell script. It would need to reach across my network to our health care facilities, seek out the specific laptop using the laptops domain name. Log into the laptop, look in a specific file folder on the root of C, then check for a specific file which is our electronic medical records backup. Once it finds what it's looking for, it will send a report back with information on all 65 laptops.

Comment: Is powershell not a good thing to try and do this with?

Comment: The level of guidance you're looking for is beyond the mandate of this site. I recommend starting with the linked documentation and making a solution attempt yourself. If you get stuck doing that and have a specific question, you can ask it here. See [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rough overview on how to remote execute commands with PowerShell.

1. Enable PSRemoting with `Enable-PSRemoting` [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enable-psremoting?view=powershell-7)
2. Establish a remote connection with `Enter-PSSession -ComputerName testserver123.global.local`
3. This opens a prompt of the remote server where you can run commands. Your PS prompt will get a prefix indicating the remote server.

A useful link is here from [4sysops](https://4sysops.com/wiki/enable-powershell-remoting/)

Comment: Thank You So Much Alex_P, the link is most helpful. I think I can piece it out from there.